# Почему возникает ошибка IndentationError: unexpected indent?

Tags: python, windows

Установил питон под Windows 10 64bit. Работает на Anaconda. Окружение python 3.4. Установил theano.

`import theano` работает при построчном вводе в консоль.
Когда пытаюсь запустить любой файл с примером, с theano связи нету.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если бы вы перевели текст ошибки, вы бы поняли, что у вас проблема с отступами.
Обратите внимание на отступ перед `import`.

Напоминаю, что в python блоки кода разграничиваются отступами.

> Если питон счёл, что у вас вложенность кода обозначается четырьмя
>   пробелами, а именно эта строка отбита одним табом, то будет такая
>   ошибка.

На основе [этого](http://djbook.ru/forum/topic/1637/#post-10745) ответа.

В данном случае отступ вообще следует удалить.

Comment: Окей , у меня такая же проблема но в коде .( Я учусь и решил написать простой калькулятор) Но удаляю абсолютно все отступы которые присутствуют в коде и все равно также ошибка .